# Constrain generic type by swift enum

Tags: swift, generics, enums

I would like to constrain a generic type in Swift by the choice of different enum cases.

Below, a code example:

```
enum Test {
  case T1
  case T2
}

enum T1 {
  case one
  case two
}

enum T2 {
  case three
  case four
}


indirect enum Foo<T> {
  case empty
  case cons(T, Foo<T>)
}

let x: Foo<T1> = .cons(.one, .empty)
```

I have a first Enum which contains two cases with T1 and T2.
I'm trying to constrain the type T in Foo Enum to have a collection of types available, which are T1 and T2 in my example.
When I declare `x`, the allowed types are `T1`or `T2` contain in Test, not another type.
Hence, only types in Enum `Test` must be allowed.

My question: Is it possible to use my Enum to constrain the generic type ? If yes, how ?
Otherwise, how can I do ?

Comment: To restate what I think you're asking... is it possible to have a generic type that could be either types A or B or C, but not others. And the answer is no. You can constrain to a protocol or class, or based on associated types of a protocol

Comment: Thanks  for your answers, you understood my question.
Can I do this kind of things with Protocols ?

Comment: What do you mean "this kind of things"? If you mean, can you constrain to a protocol, then yes - that's exactly what I said in my comment. Maybe I misunderstand what you're asking...

Comment: Sorry, I had to be more precise. I wanted to know if I can constrain how I would like (so T1 and T2) with protocols.
Imagine that I can have 10 different types to constrain, how should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Method 1

According to the comments, I think this is what you are trying to accomplish:

```swift
protocol MyEnums {}

enum T1: MyEnums { case one, two }
enum T2: MyEnums { case one, two }
enum T3 { case one, two }

let foo: [MyEnums] = [T1.one, T1.two, T2.one, T2.two]
```

The array can only contain objects conforming to the `MyEnums` protocol.

 Note how enum `T3` cannot be stored within `foo` because it does not conform to the protocol `MyEnums`.

---

## Method 2

Here's a little more. You actually *can* do what you were asking:

```swift
protocol MyEnums {}
enum T1: MyEnums { case one, two }
enum T2: MyEnums { case one, two }
enum T3 { case one, two }
indirect enum Foo<T: MyEnums> {
  case empty
  case cons(T, Foo<T>)
}
```

Note that the generic is `<T: MyEnums>`.
This code will do exactly what you want. It can store enums conforming to the `MyEnums` protocol. So you can store enums T1 and T2 if they are conformed to `MyEnums`, but not T3 because it is not.

So you will be able to do this:

```swift
let x: Foo = .cons(T1.one, .cons(T1.two, .empty))
```

However this second method does not allow for this:

```swift
let x: Foo = .cons(T1.one, .cons(T2.one, .empty))
```

I'll try to see if we can do this..

---

## Method 3

I got it!! This is exactly what you were asking for:

```swift
protocol MyEnums {}
protocol MyEnums1: MyEnums {}

enum T1: MyEnums1 { case one, two }
enum T2: MyEnums1 { case one, two }
enum T3 { case one, two }

indirect enum Foo<T: MyEnums> {
  case empty
  case cons(MyEnums1, Foo<T>)
}

let x: Foo<T1> = .cons(T1.one, .cons(T2.one, .empty))
print(x)
```

It required 2 protocols, but I finally fixed Method 2. Remember, you can only put in objects conforming to `MyEnums1`, so `T3` is not an option. Perfect!

This was a very cool question to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! That's exactly what I wanted !